OpenApiGenerator not setting modelAnnotations on generation
My task in the build.gradle.kts:
tasks.named<org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask>("openApiGenerate") {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set(file("src/main/resources/api.yaml").absolutePath)
    outputDir.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-src").get().asFile.absolutePath)
    apiPackage.set("example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("example.invoker")
    configOptions.set(
        mapOf(
            "delegatePattern" to "true",
            "useSpringBoot3" to "true",
            "dateLibrary" to "java8",
            "interfaceOnly" to "true",
            "useTags" to "true",
            "useBeanValidation" to "true", // For bean validation
            "useLombokAnnotations" to "true" // Optional, if lombok is used in the project
        )
    )

    // Additional annotations
    additionalProperties.set(
        mapOf(
            "modelAnnotations" to "@jakarta.persistence.Entity @jakarta.persistence.Table",
            "fieldAnnotations" to "@JsonProperty"
        )
    )

    typeMappings.set(
        mapOf(
            "DateTime" to "java.time.OffsetDateTime",
            "UUID" to "java.util.UUID"
        )
    )
}

My dependencies:
// SpringDoc OpenAPI for Swagger UI
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14")

// OpenAPI Generator Dependencies
implementation("org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.2")

The used openApi file to generate the classes:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Example API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /example:
    get:
      summary: Get Example
      operationId: getExample
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ExampleModel'
components:
  schemas:
    ExampleModel:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        name:
          type: string
      required:
        - id
        - name

The generated output:
package org.openapitools.model;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;


import java.util.*;
import jakarta.annotation.Generated;

/**
 * ExampleModel
 */

@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-07-04T17:27:45.274895500+02:00[Europe/Berlin]", comments = "Generator version: 7.7.0")
public class ExampleModel {

  private java.util.UUID id;

  private String name;

  public ExampleModel() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Constructor with only required parameters
   */
  public ExampleModel(java.util.UUID id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public ExampleModel id(java.util.UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get id
   * @return id
   */
  @NotNull @Valid 
  @Schema(name = "id", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("id")
  public java.util.UUID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(java.util.UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public ExampleModel name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
   */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "name", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    ExampleModel exampleModel = (ExampleModel) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, exampleModel.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.name, exampleModel.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class ExampleModel {\n");
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}



With the additionalProperties set, I would expect that not only the @JsonProperty annotation would be generated but also the @jakarta.persistence.Entity and @jakarta.persistence.Table annotation on top of the class.
So my expected result would be something like this:
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-07-04T16:40:24.719345200+02:00[Europe/Berlin]")
@Entity
@Table(name = "example_model")
public class ExampleModel {

However, my desired output would look somewhat more like this:
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-07-04T16:40:24.719345200+02:00[Europe/Berlin]")
@Entity
@Table(name = "example_model")
public class ExampleModel {

  @Id
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private UUID id;

  @JsonProperty("name")
  @jakarta.persistence.Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  // Getter and Setter methods

  // equals, hashCode, toString methods
}

I know that in the worst case I could add the annotations in the openapi.yaml manually, but I would prefer if there is a way to automatically add the annotations to it. However, for now I'm stuck on the @Table and @Entity generation problem.
